# Dynamically loading a component in Angular 2 requires Traceur?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-compiler-cli

My code should load a component based on a customer name and a setting, both received as strings from the backend.

I tried using the Compiler to compile the module and then get the component factory, however when trying to compile, angular seems to require **Traceur** which I didn't install or reference. Angular 2 docs don't mention it at all.

Is Traceur mandatory for runtime compilation of a module, or am I doing something wrong?

```
Error loading http://localhost:8099/customers/zd/march/traceur
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:8099/ng_app/app/customer-page/zd/zd.module.ts
Error loading http://localhost:8099/ng_app/app/customer-page/zd/zd.module.ts
```

- Traceur is obviously not at /customers/zd/march/traceur, but why is it required?

Code (only the dynamic loading part, for brevity):
The failure results of the call to `compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)`.

```
                let customer = self.service.getCustomerName();
                let customer_view = feedbackChannel.customSettings.view;
                console.log('loading module for customer ' + customer);
                System.import('/ng_app/app/customer-page/' + customer + '/' + customer + '.module.ts')
                    .then((module) => {
                        console.log('compiling module for customer ' + customer);
                        return self.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module);
                    })
                    .then((moduleWithFactories) => {
                        console.log('loading class for customer view ' + customer_view);
                        self.componentFactory = moduleWithFactories.componentFactories.find((factory) => {
                            return (factory.componentType.name === customer_view);
                        });
                        console.log('Is customer view loaded? ' + (self.componentFactory != null));

                        // try loading the component here
                        let viewContainerRef = this.customerViewHost.viewContainerRef;
                        viewContainerRef.clear();

                        viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log('Error when loading component: ' + err);
                    });
```

The module being loaded:

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';

import { ZDPageComponent }     from './zd-page.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ZDPageComponent],
  exports:      [ ZDPageComponent ]
})
export class ZDModule { }
```

package.json, in case I'm missing/misusing some angular reference:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "body-parser": "1.10.x",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "busboy": "^0.2.9",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "configstore": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-loki": "^1.0.9",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "email-addresses": "^2.0.2",
    "express": "^4.10.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.1",
    "express-xml-bodyparser": "^0.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^1.0.0",
    "konfig": "^0.2.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.8",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "plivo": "^0.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "request": "^2.79.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "sendgrid": "^4.7.1",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.41",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.5",
    "useragent": "^2.1.11",
    "winston": "^2.3.0",
    "winston-loggly-bulk": "^1.3.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.9.8",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node npm_scripts/postinstall.js",
    "startDev": "concurrent \"tsc -w\" \"node tm_web.js\"",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
    "browserify": "browserify -s main client/public/ng_app/dist/main.js > client/public/ng_app/dist/bundle.js",
    "minify": "uglifyjs client/public/ng_app/dist/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output client/public/ng_app/dist/bundle.min.js",
    "build_prod": "npm run build && npm run browserify && npm run minify",
    "start": "node tm_web.js",
    "migrate": "node ./server/model_migartion/migrate.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "rxjs-system-bundle": "^5.1.1-2"
  }
}
```

system.js loader, in case I'm missing something here:

```
  (function(global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'angular:': '/assets/javascript/angular/'
        },
        bundles: {
            "angular:Rx.system.min.js": [
                "rxjs",
                "rxjs/*",
                "rxjs/operator/*",
                "rxjs/observable/*",
                "rxjs/scheduler/*",
                "rxjs/symbol/*",
                "rxjs/add/operator/*",
                "rxjs/add/observable/*",
                "rxjs/util/*"
            ]
        }, 
        map: {
            'app': 'app',

            '@angular/core': 'angular:core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'angular:common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'angular:compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'angular:platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'angular:platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'angular:http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'angular:router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'angular:forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            //'rxjs': 'angular:Rx.min.js',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'angular:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
                    './app/*.js': {
                        loader: './systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
            },
            rxjs: {
                //defaultExtension: 'js'
                defaultExtension: false
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

tsconfig, in case the issue is with how typescript compilers should be defined:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "client/public/ng_app/dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "client/public/ng_app/app",
        "client/public/ng_app/main.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `self`?

Comment: old practice across js environments - `this` is sometimes not correctly bound within promises / callbacks, so I store `this` in `self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you should import transpiled `js` file instead of origin `ts`

Moreover i would compile `NgModule` class

```
System.import(...)
  .then((module: any) => module['ZDModule'])
  .then((module) => self.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module))
  .then(...
```

Comment: Now the module is loaded but throws an error - No NgModule metadata found for 'Module'.
My module is rather simple (see above).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to compile `ZDModule`. Check `.then((module) => { console.log(module);`

Comment: Seems it should be `return self.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module['ZDModule']);`

Comment: You're on the right track - JSON.stringify(module) shows only {"__esModule":true}
Looks like the module.exports is not there for some reason... looking into it, will update once I figure it out

Comment: OK, your solution works even though JSON.stringify doesn't show the property, thanks

Comment: Put `debugger` and you will see the whole object